# Why does urllib.parse.urlencode not change '_' into %5F?

Tags: python-3.x, post, urllib, urlencode

I am writing POST request for game I am trying to make scripts for. For this post, I am using the common `req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, data=params, headers=headers)` First though, I have a dictionary of the data needed for the request, and I must encode it with `params = urllib.parse.urlencode(OrderedDict[])`

However, this gives me a string, but not the proper one! It will give me:

```
&x=_1&y_=2&_z_=3
```

But, the way the game encodes things, it should be:

```
&x=%5F1&y%5F=2&%5Fz%5F=3
```

So mine doesn't encode the underscores to be "%5F". How do I fix this? If I can, I have the params that the game uses (in url, pre-encoded for), would I be able to use that in the data field of the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underscores don't need to be encoded, because they are valid characters in URLs.

As per [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> Unsafe:
>
> Characters can be unsafe for a number of reasons.  The space
>      character is unsafe because significant spaces may disappear and
>      insignificant spaces may be introduced when URLs are transcribed or
>      typeset or subjected to the treatment of word-processing programs.
>      The characters `<` and `>` are unsafe because they are used as the
>      delimiters around URLs in free text; the quote mark (`"`) is used to
>      delimit URLs in some systems.  The character `#` is unsafe and should
>      always be encoded because it is used in World Wide Web and in other
>      systems to delimit a URL from a fragment/anchor identifier that might
>      follow it.  The character `%` is unsafe because it is used for
>      encodings of other characters.  Other characters are unsafe because
>      gateways and other transport agents are known to sometimes modify
>      such characters. These characters are `{`, `}`, `|`, `\`, `^`, `~`,
>      `[`, `]`, and `` ` ``.
>
> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL.

So the reason `_` is not replaced by `%5F` is the same reason that `a` is not replaced by `%61`: it's just not necessary. Web servers don't (or shouldn't) care either way.

In case the web server you're trying to use does care (but please check first if that's the case), you'll have to do some manual work, as urllibs quoting [does not support quoting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) `_`:

> urllib.parse.quote(string, safe='/', encoding=None, errors=None)
>
> Replace special characters in string using the `%xx` escape. Letters, digits, and the characters `_.-` are never quoted.

You can probably wrap `quote()` with your own function and pass that to `urlencode()`. Something like this (fully untested):

```
def extra_quote(*args, **kwargs):
    quoted = urllib.pars.quote(*args, **kwargs)
    return str.replace(quoted, '_', '%5F')

urllib.parse.urlencode(query, quote_via=extraquote)
```

Comment: Thank! I read over my code with what you said and. . .  it turns out I was using `int(time.time())` instead of `int(time())` for the timestamp . . . >.<